# Calling a function from another namespace in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript

I'm a newbie with CojureScript because I got the LISP itch some months ago and then I migrated the API to Clojure and I'm loving it. Now I want to migrate the frontend too but this is my first week with CLJS.

So, I have this function:

```
(defn foo []
   (events/listen (gdom/getElement "icon-add") EventType.CLICK
      (fn [e] (.log js/console (str ">>> VALUE >>>>> "  e)))))
```

the function works great in the core.cljs file, but if I move it to users.cljs file and I call it from the core namespace with:

```
(ns zentaur.core
  (:require [zentaur.users :as users]

(users/foo)
```

the DOM element "icon-add" is never found and instead I get the error message:

```
Uncaught goog.asserts.AssertionError {message: "Assertion failed: Listener can not be null.", reportErrorToServer: true,
```

in the browser console. If I move the function back to core.cljs, all works fine again. Then  my question is: how can I move a function to another NS and be sure it keeps working?

**UPDATE**:

I noted that if I call the listener directly in users.cljs:

```
(events/listen (gdom/getElement "icon-add") EventType.CLICK
   (fn [] (.log js/console (str ">>> events/listen in users ns"))))
```

(I mean out of any function), all works fine, the code find the DOM element.

**SECOND UPDATE**

Thanks a lot for your answers but this issue looks like a "compiling time" problem. All the listeners:

```
(events/listen (gdom/getElement "icon-add") EventType.CLICK foo-funct)
```

must be loaded when CLJS runs at first time. Loading another **ns** is a "second time" thing and then the DOM is not reachable anymore.

Comment: Your second update leads me to think that your `foo-funct` is not in the scope, when you call `events/listen`. If it is in the same file, does the definition precede your call? If in separate namespace, are you requiring it properly?

Answer (score 3):

In the core namespace you need to `require` the 2nd namespace:

```
(ns xyz.core
  (:require [xyz.users :as users] ))

(users/foo)  ; call the function
```

This assumes your code is laid out as

```
src
src/xyz
src/xyz/core.cljs
src/xyz/users.cljs
```

There are also [some good ideas here](https://stuartsierra.com/2016/clojure-how-to-ns.html) on various tradeoffs in naming and references to other namespaces.

Comment: Yes, I already have that "require" stuff. The function is executed but the DOM element is never reached.

Answer (score 3):

The user namespace is special in that it is designed to be pre-loaded, and for development only. It is also the only time you will ever see a namespace that does not have a parent package. I say this just to warn you off using `user` as a namespace name - doing so will just cause confusion - whether it has a parent package or not.

Your problem seems to be that one of the arguments to `events/listen` is somehow returning `nil`. Do you have `gdom` as a require in `zentaur.users`, so: `[goog.dom :as gdom]`?

Answer (score 2):

[Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) library throws the assertion error because your listener function, i.e., the third parameter to `listen` is `null`.

Looking at the source code for the library, [it tries to wrap the third parameter into a `Listener`](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/events/events.js#L180), and the error string is produced from [this failed assertion for a truthy value](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/events/events.js#L985).

I often have similar problem, when I accidentally put extra parenthesis around the function. In effect, this leads to the function being called immediately after its declaration. This may happen without warning, even when your declared function requires one or more parameters; ClojureScript runs on JS, which does not check the arity when calling the function. Since the body of your listener is just `console.log`, which returns `null`, you would be trying to assign the `null` as listener.

You did note that the code example that you give is working in `core.cljs`. Indeed, the example does not show any obvious reason why the function is null in this case. Perhaps there was a small error in copy-pasting this function to `users.cljs`, e.g., extra parenthesis added?